# Push down automaton for Language of same number of as and bs

Tags: context-free, automata, pushdown-automata

**The task**

> Find a pushdown automaton $M$, so that $L(M)=\{w \in \{a,b\}^*\ |\ |w|_a=|w|_b\}$, where $|w|_a$ denotes the number of $a$s in a word $w$.

**My solution**

I'm using the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) notation.
$$M = (Q, \Sigma, \Gamma, \delta, q_0, Z_0, \{q_0\})$$
$$Q=\{q_0\}, \Sigma = \{a,b\}, \Gamma = \{Z_0, A,B\}$$
$$\delta\text{ has the following instructions:}$$
$$(q_0, \varepsilon, Z_0, q_0, \varepsilon),$$
$$(q_0, a, Z_0, q_0, AZ_0),$$
$$(q_0, b, Z_0, q_0, BZ_0),$$
$$(q_0, a, A, q_0, AA),$$
$$(q_0, b, A, q_0, \varepsilon),$$
$$(q_0, b, B, q_0, BB)\text{ and}$$
$$(q_0, a, B, q_0, \varepsilon).$$

**Questions**

1. Is this correct? Can it be simplified?
2. If so, how can I argue (not neccessarily proof) its correctness?

Comment: To argue why it's correct, write down what you thought when you constructed the PDA.

Comment: copy-paste error in your last instruction: it duplicates an earlier one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As adrianN and Yuval say, correctness is shown by explaining your ideas, in particular what the automaton stores in its states and stack.

Just as a fun fact: you have constructed a single state PDA, which essentially means you have constructed a context-free grammar. The construction is reverse from the one given in a remark in Wikipedia (concerning CFG in Greibach normal form).

In this case your productions are equivalent to

$Z\to \varepsilon$,
$Z\to aAZ$,
$Z\to bBZ$,
$A\to aAA$,
$A\to b$,
$B\to bBB$,
$B\to a$.

You can shave off one production and use less nonterminals by starting with the grammar $S\to SS$, $S\to aSb$, $S\to bSa$, $S\to\varepsilon$, which is a variant of the well-formed parenthesis grammar in wikipedia. This is not yet a PDA,to this you need a more Greibach-like format:

$S\to SS$, $S\to aSB$, $S\to bSA$, $S\to\varepsilon$, $A\to a$, $B\to b$.

More efficient perhaps, but the stacks of your original PDA have a clear meaning, helping its correctness proof.

Comment: Thanks! This looks just like a grammar I learned about earlier, so I can make use of that.

Answer (score 2):

The usual approach is to prove by induction the following kind of statement:

> The set of configurations reachable from the initial state upon reading a word $w$ is ...

Here ... depends on $w$. Having proved this kind of statement, you can deduce which words are accepted by your machine, hence proving its correctness.